# data-bind in knockout.js Cart editor example

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

Hello I am working with the Cart editor example from knockout.js and I am having a data-bind conflict.  I want to write the following code:

```
<td data-bind='visible:(category().name=="Tops")'>Zipper:<br/>
<select data-bind='options: category() ? category().zipper : null, optionsText: "name", optionsCaption: "Select...", value: zipper'></select></td>
```

but since I have bound category().name to the  element, the select element does not properly fill.  If I remove the data-bind on the  element and place it in the  element only as shown below then everything works fine.

```
   <td>Zipper:<br/>
<select data-bind='visible:(category().name=="Tops"), options: category() ? category().zipper : null, optionsText: "name", optionsCaption: "Select...", value: zipper'></select></td>
```

I think somehow putting the data-bind in the  element is locking it so it doesn't work correctly in the  but I'm not quite sure why.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax that you are using should not cause a problem.  If there is something further to your issue you could try to reproduce it off of this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/WLwRH/

It also shows a way in Knockout 2.0 (out today 12/21/2011) to write it a little cleaner:

```
<tr data-bind="with: category">
    <td data-bind="visible: name == 'Tops'">
        <select data-bind="options: zipper, optionsText: 'name', optionsCaption: 'Select...', value: $root.zipper"></select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use "display: none" attribute to hide or" visibility: hidden".

Working code [here (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/gbsandeep/PUTDf/)

```
<div id="container">
    <span data-bind='text: category().name == "Tops"'> </span>

    <td data-bind='attr: {style:category().name=="Tops"?"display:none":"display:"}'>Zipper:
        <select data-bind='options: category()? category().zipper: null, optionsText: "name", optionsCaption: "Select..."'></select>
    </td>

</div>

var viewModel = {
    category: ko.observable({
        name: 'Tps', // Change this to Tops to hide
        zipper: [{
            name: 'stack'},
        {
            name: 'over'},
        {
            name: 'flow'}]
    })
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```